# PHP mail Failed to connect

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to send an email from the server using php
this is the code

```
$from = "Sandra Sender <dev@mywebsite.space>";
$to = "Ramona Recipient <myemail3@gmail.com>";
$subject = "Hi!";
$body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
$host = "webmail.mywebsite.space";
$username = "dev@mywebsite.space";
$password = "JjLvUZIoeeI4";
$headers = array ('From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
 'Subject' => $subject);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
 array ('host' => $host,
  'auth' => true,
  'username' => $username,
  'password' => $password));
  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
  if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
```

but am getting this error

> Failed to connect to webmail.@mywebsite.space:25 [SMTP: Failed to connect socket: Connection refused (code: -1, response: )]

Am i missing something here?

iptables

```
    To                         Action      From
  --                         ------      ----
  80,443/tcp (Apache Full)   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
  22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
  22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
  25                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
  25/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
  80,443/tcp (Apache Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
  22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
  22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
  25 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
  25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: Have you double checked host and ports?

Comment: yes this is my ip table

Comment: To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80,443/tcp (Apache Full)   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25                         ALLOW IN    Anywhere
25/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
80,443/tcp (Apache Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere v6
25 (v6)                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere v6
25/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere v6

Comment: Maybe its related to the dot "." on:
$host = "webmail.@mywebsite.space";

Comment: no it's not the problem

Comment: Have you verified connectivity?  Try telnetting to that host on port 25.